# Adding constraint in Unity3D transform.rotate (on character controller)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

So this is a part of my controller code:

```
    float rotLeftRight = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity;
    transform.Rotate(0, rotLeftRight, 0,Space.Self);
```

It works well, but I want to restrict my player from making sharp turns when running above a certain speed. I've been trying to use mathf.clamp function on rotLeft right but results are random at best.

Comment: It sounds like you want help designing an algorithm to prevent sharp turns. Can you explain this in more detail with examples?

Comment: Stack overflow is designed to help you with questions, not to write code for you. What have you tried so far?